# Cocos2d playing animation in second time caused crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I used cocos2d 2.0, observed crash when sprite animation switched. Here is code

```
@interface PPActor : CCSprite
{
    CCRepeatForever *pirateIdleAnim;
    CCSequence      *mPirateDashAnim;
    CCRepeatForever *mPirateRocketAnim;

}
```

//Case 1: Crashed on playing second time

```
-(void)loadAnim
{

   CCAnimate *AnimActions  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
   id calFun = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dashAnimDone)];                                        
   mPirateDashAnim = [CCSequence actions:AnimActions, calFun, nil];
   mPirateDashAnim.tag = kTagDashAnim;
}

-(void)runDashAnim
{
       [self stopActionByTag: kTagDashAnim];
       [self runAction:mPirateDashAnim];
}
```

//Case 2: No crash, but shows memory leaks…(used retain)

```
-(void)loadAnim
{

   CCAnimate *AnimActions  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
   id calFun = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dashAnimDone)];                                     
   mPirateDashAnim = [[CCSequence actions:AnimActions, calFun, nil] retain];
   mPirateDashAnim.tag = kTagDashAnim;
}

-(void)runDashAnim
{
       [self stopActionByTag: kTagDashAnim];
       [self runAction:mPirateDashAnim];
}
```

//Case 3: again crash observed

```
-(void)loadAnim
{

   CCAnimate *AnimActions  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
   id calFun = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dashAnimDone)];                                     
   mPirateDashAnim = [CCSequence actions:AnimActions, calFun, nil];
   mPirateDashAnim.tag = kTagDashAnim;
}

-(void)runDashAnim
{
       [self stopActionByTag: kTagDashAnim];
       [self runAction:[mPirateDashAnim copy]];
}
```

How can I overcome this crash and memory leaks?

Comment: You could create a property for mPirateDashAnim and retain/release it properly in the setter ! Looks like you're having trouble with the object pointed here (if you retain it too much -> leaks, if you don't retain -> crash)... There is a standard way of dealing with properties here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Comment: @AndyM, see here case is different, at the end of runAction memory is auto released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you always call loadAnim before runDashAnim? Because actions are one-time object. When the action finishes, it releases itself. You have to create the action again.

Please do not follow said "best practices" that recommend retaining actions. It's bad practice because unless you know an action's internal behavior (ie code) there's the risk of creating memory leaks or crashes because not all actions can be reused in that way.

Comment: only once called loadAnim, and loading frames every time takes time..what's best solution for this problem sir?